# Check how long a HDD has been used in LINUX

Tags: linux, hard-disk

Under Linux, is it possible to check how much hours a HDD has been used? and how much hours are left for that HDD?

So yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean? What does it mean for HDD to be "used", what does it mean for HDD to have "n hours left"?

Comment: I want to see/check the lifetime of my HARD DISK DRIVE .. How much hours he has spinnend AND how much hours he have left ... @MatthewRock

Answer (score 5):

```
# smartctl --attributes "${disk}" | grep Power_On_Hours
```

Or

```
# smartctl -A "${disk}" | grep Power_On_Hours
```

Replace `"${disk}"` with your disk (for example `/dev/sda`).

You need to install [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/).

Answer (score 3):

The tool is called `smartctl` if you are searching for CLI.

If you prefer graphical application, you can read SMART data using **Disks** (`gnome-disks`), where you navigate to your disk, click on the menu and select **SMART Data and Self-tests** option. You are interested in *Power-On Hours* row.

The `gnome-disks` application is part of `gnome-disk-utility` package in CentOS/RHEL/Fedora.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the smartctl gives me a error in terminal, where can i find Disks? ( gnome-disks ) ? http://i.imgur.com/TCtdnM2.png

Comment: It is not an error, but usage information, you should read if you want to use it. Just write `gnome-disks` into terminal.

Comment: bash: gnome-disks: command not found
and if i want to download : yum install gnome-disks - i get this : No package gnome-disks available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: `sudo you install gnome-disk-utility`