# Check toshiba hdd power on hours or hours used

Tags: hard-disk, smartctl, toshiba

Using a toshiba hdd I am unable to get power on hours or anything similar. Requesting assistance.

[Check how long a HDD has been used in LINUX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250577/check-how-long-a-hdd-has-been-used-in-linux)
From this forum post and using -all it shows lots of useful information, but nothing related to power on hours.

Toshiba drive: Toshiba 16TB Enterprise HDD SAS 12Gb/s 512e 7200 RPM 512MB Cache 3.5" Internal Hard Drive MG08SCA16TE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How to find power on hours for a toshiba hard drive?